How to reduce the precision of a shape without creating duplicated points?
I need to provide the description of a field to the EUDR reporting system. In the description of the regulation the rules specify "6 digits precision" on geospatial coordinates. As we are recording our fields using Fulcrum software and a phone, we get 13 digits. To respect the reporting system requirements I need to provide a exactly "6 digits" .geojson.
In consequence, the following .geojson becomes ill has the simple trimming of digits (that's what they do) creates duplicated points.
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [[
                    [76.1769942018803, 11.5715250438649],
                    [76.178453589337, 11.5719241189971],
                    [76.178142386675, 11.5733371002342],
                    [76.1763518258582, 11.5733400106339],
                    [76.1763267786331, 11.5722612874711],
                    [76.1763267788063, 11.5722612874711],
                    [76.1769942018803, 11.5715250438649]
                ]]
            },
            "properties": {"plot_id": "1"}
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [[
                    [76.2100939944995, 11.5755956944579],
                    [76.2103450806586, 11.5768628129501],
                    [76.2099792604253, 11.5770728610726],
                    [76.2095611276718, 11.5766269708728],
                    [76.2090376056254, 11.576769149322],
                    [76.2085884860924, 11.5762962526216],
                    [76.2083029379301, 11.5758244854722],
                    [76.2081820693426, 11.5756453421987],
                    [76.2086545398898, 11.575387404133],
                    [76.2094402243094, 11.5750519407588],
                    [76.20989438543, 11.5749788408455],
                    [76.2098943855599, 11.5749788408455],
                    [76.2100939944995, 11.5755956944579]
                ]]
            },
            "properties": {"plot_id": "2"}
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [[
                    [76.2020517628569, 11.6045600436763],
                    [76.202424332126, 11.6043986058752],
                    [76.2026449017872, 11.6048624924106],
                    [76.2025437316198, 11.6048863785623],
                    [76.2023618330256, 11.6049767927598],
                    [76.2023618330689, 11.6049767927175],
                    [76.2020517628569, 11.6045600436763]
                ]]
            },
            "properties": {"plot_id": "3"}
        }
    ]
}

Is there a way to reduce the number of digits in my coordinates and delete the duplicated points that could appear in the process using python and geopandas?

Out of interest, could you provide links to "the description of the regulation the rules specify "at least 6 digits precision" on geospatial coordinates" and the contradicting opinions from "developers of the European Commission"?

I need to get back to the first FAQ but let me dig

I wanted to answer you so I dug the FAQ, the first one stated "at least 6 digits" and was replaced in the 2 next ones by "with 6 digits". So the developer aligned on the last description. All my GPS products will give me 13 digits, so I'll continue storing them this way but thank you for pointing out my misunderstanding. Updating the question to avoid being disrespectful.

I found some FAQ https://green-business.ec.europa.eu/deforestation-regulation-implementation/traceability-and-geolocation-commodities-subject-eudr_en#information-on-geolocation-data but there is nothing about digits. What FAQ do you read? Nothing about being disrespectful, I just want to know where to find the documentation. I guess that EUDR stands for "EU Regulation on Deforestation-free Products".

I was refering to this one. the 6 digits are mentioned several time in the first paragraphs about "traceability": https://www.europarl.europa.eu/meetdocs/2014_2019/plmrep/COMMITTEES/ENVI/DV/2023/11-20/FAQ-Deforestation_Regulation_EN.pdf

The geopandas set_precision function will round the coordinates but will also make sure the output is a valid geometry.

Coordinates will be rounded if a precision grid is less precise than
the input geometry. Duplicated vertices will be dropped from lines and
polygons for grid sizes greater than 0

As you noticed just rounding the points can lead to duplicate points, but it can also lead to self-intersections,...:
# Round the coordinates to 6 decimals
gdf.geometry = gdf.geometry.set_precision(grid_size=0.000001)


Sure, first reduce the number of digits and then run the geopandas.GeoSeries.remove_repeated_points
